# Set ClickOnce ApplicationVersion and MinimumRequiredVersion to date in VSTS Build

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, clickonce, azure-pipelines

I have a visual studio build step in a CI build that creates the clickonce files of a desktop application using the MSBuild arguments below:

```
/target:publish /p:ApplicationVersion=$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth).$(Build.BuildId) /p:MinimumRequiredVersion=$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth).$(Build.BuildId) /p:InstallUrl=$(InstallUrl)
```

The $(Build.BuildId) and $(InstallUrl) variables get replaced with their correct values but the $(Year:yyyy), $(Month) and $(DayOfMonth) variables do not get replaced. I am using the same variables to set the Build number format on the General tab and they get replaced correctly. Is it not possible to use the date based variables in a build step in VSTS?

Edit: It appears using $(Build.BuildNumber) would work but I like to include the build definition name in the build number format, which obviously won't work for the version.

Comment: Do you solve this issue with Luca's solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(Year:yyyy)`, `$(Month)`, `$(DayOfMonth)` are tokens you could use only in the Build Number Format field, not anywhere else.

I would suggest you to create yourself those variables on the fly, leveraging the following script run by the PowerShell task (with an Inline Script) just before your Visual Studio Build task:

```
$date = get-date
write-host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Year;]$(($date).year)"
write-host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Month;]$(($date).month)"
write-host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Day;]$(($date).day)"
```

Then you could use `$(Year)`, `$(Month)` and `$(Day)` in place of the tokens you currently use as additional MSBuild arguments.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I'm not a fan of having to add powershell scripts for something this small but it will work. I think I may just change the build number format and deal with that though.

Comment: Why on Earth $(Year), $(Month), etc.  are not initialized when the agent initiates, is something that's beyond me.